# Windows 11 22H2 WSL error - Windows cannot access \\wsl.localhost

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-11, windows-11-v22h2

I have installed WSL on Windows 11 and Ubuntu-22.04 in it. However, when I click on the Linux icon on the side panel,

[image: Linux icon]

I get the below error message:

[image: Error message]

WSL successfully opens Ubuntu-22.04:

[image: WSL details]

Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Comment: `\\wsl.localhost`  is handled by a service.  You should make it's running.  ALso you need to start Ubunu instance.

Comment: @Ramhound could you please elaborate with some details?

Comment: @PManjunatha This is, well, disappointing -- I get the feeling the WSL team believes they had made the 9P mechanism a lot more robust in recent releases.  What you are seeing is almost certainly a bug.  There's likely a solution -- I just don't know what it is yet.  A couple of question -- (a) Is this a fresh install of 22H2 or an upgrade from 22H1?  (b) Did you use `wsl --install -d Ubuntu-22.04` or some other variation?

Comment: Also, if my answer doesn't help, can you run `ubuntu2004.exe`?  I prefer the `wsl` command myself, but there's a chance you'll get the 0x80070002 error with the `ubuntu2004` command, and that might lead us in the right direction.  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds, it is an upgrade from 21H2 to 22H2. I had this issue the moment after the upgrade. When I clicked the Linux icon, the error message popped. Later I uninstalled Ubuntu for Windows and the "Windows Subsystem for Linux" feature and rebooted. Later, I installed it by enabling the "Windows Subsystem for Linux" feature and using the Microsoft store to install Ubuntu 22.04. Even the reinstallation of Ubuntu 22.04 did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Given the new information in the comments, I'm going to rewrite this and suggest a couple of different attempts.  I still don't have high hopes for them, but they are relatively easy processes.

Based on the comments, you:

- Had Windows 11 21H2 (22000) with WSL installed
- Upgraded to Windows 11 22H2 (22621)
- Started seeing the issue
- Uninstalled Ubuntu and disabled the WSL feature
- Rebooted
- Re-enabled the Windows Subsystem for Linux feature
- Installed Ubuntu 22.04 from the Store
- Are still seeing the issue

Based on that, I'm confused as to how you are at 0.66.2, but that may mean that you had it installed on 22H1.

It's important to note that disabling the Windows Subsystem for Linux *feature* no longer actually removes WSL itself if you have a Store Preview (such as 0.66.2) installed.  Under 22H2, at least, it only turns off WSL1 support.

So let's try this two ways.

First, try rolling back to the "GA" WSL that comes with Windows (the actual "feature"):

- Uninstall the existing *"Windows Subsystem for Linux Preview"* by either right-clicking it in the Start menu and *"Uninstall"* or through *"Add or remove programs" in Settings.
- Reboot
- Under *Settings* -> *Turn Windows features on or off*, check to make sure that the *Windows Subsystem for Linux* feature and the *Virtual Machine Platform* feature (or *Hyper-V*) are enabled -- They should already/still be.

Try the Linux share again.

If that doesn't work, my second suggestion would be to try the latest "Pre-release".  These are considered slightly less stable than the 0.66.2 Preview that `wsl --install` currently enables, but it's always possible to roll back to 0.66.2 (or any previous release).  To install (or rollback):

1. Download 0.68.4 from the [Releases](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/releases) page in the WSL Github repo.
2. Start an Administrator PowerShell and:

   ```
   Add-AppxPackage <path.to>/Microsoft.WSL_0.68.4.0_x64_ARM64.msixbundle
   wsl --version # to confirm
   ```
3. Reboot just to make sure everything is restarted properly.

See if that makes a difference with the Linux share.

Comment: I have previously installed the WSL in Windows 11 21H2.

Comment: @PManjunatha Ok, still worth trying the 0.68.4.0.  I'd give it only about a 20% chance of fixing the problem, but that's the best option I have for you to try at the moment.